# How to get a Date-Time Difference (Oracle SQL) and Evaluate Against a Number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out how take a date-time in the future and subtract it from now, and then see if that value (in days) is less than 30.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you subtract two dates you get the number of days. Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: If the date is in the future, and you subtract it FROM now, you will get a negative number. This is simple logic, it has nothing to do with computing (programming, database, etc.) Instead, what you need is very likely to subtract "now" from the future date, not the other way around. Other than that, it is not clear what you are asking; the difference of two date-times in Oracle is already the number of days (in NUMBER data type), so you can compare to 30 directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation describes [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705). If you subtract one date from another you get the result as the number of (whole or partial) days, so you can just check that number (making sure it's the right sign, as @Mathguy noted):

```
with your_table (date_col) as (
  select date '2018-08-01' from dual
  union all select date '2018-08-15' from dual
  union all select date '2018-08-16' from dual
  union all select date '2018-09-01' from dual
)
select date_col,
  date_col - sysdate as diff,
  case when date_col - sysdate >= 30 then '30+ days ahead' else '<30 days ahead' end as descr
from your_table;

DATE_COL         DIFF DESCR          
---------- ---------- --------------
2018-08-01 15.2628241 <30 days ahead
2018-08-15 29.2628241 <30 days ahead
2018-08-16 30.2628241 30+ days ahead 
2018-09-01 46.2628241 30+ days ahead
```

Comment: thank you this answered my question. Sorry my question was not clearer.